# Google Custom Search API on Android - search by uploading image file?

Tags: android, google-search, google-search-api

In my app, I would like to take the photo, and then upload it to the search engine API and receive JSON/XML with the search result, so the user can choose the most matching option.

Is it possible to use image search by uploading the image file (like you would do that in regular google image search), instead of providing the image URL?

Comment: I am searching the same +1, if you found and answer please post it.